# How to merge 2 changes that both convert a binary file to text?

Tags: git, git-merge

New to git, so not quite sure how to pull this off. Here's the situation:

Rob worked on a binary file, and converted it to text format, then made some changes.

Jon did the same.

Rob pushed his changes to origin.

Jon tries to push his changes to origin. However, he couldn't because of the merge conflict.  Jon can't merge because both changes involve Binary -> Text + changes.

Jon tries `git pull --rebase`, but still errors that "Cannot merge binary files".

What can be done? Assuming that git can't apply Jon's changes, because it can't understand the difference between the original binary file and Jon's text file, so it can't apply those changes to the file (Text) Rob had already pushed to origin.

Comment: Do you have any. gitattributes file?

Comment: I don't think so; I'm also unsure that I have a command line available to do the convert, if that's what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

If I were Jon, I would do like this:
suppose your remote branch is *master* and the url is *path/some.git*

1. `mkdir tmp
   cd tmp
   git init
   git remote add origin path/some.git
   git fetch origin master
   git checkout FETCH_HEAD`
2. use a tool like *beyond-compare* to merge Jon's changed text with tmp's master text
3. `git add .
   git commit
   git push origin HEAD:master
   cd -
   rm -rf tmp`

Answer (score 1):

Jon can try merging it, and then select which of the two files you want:

```
git pull origin master                         # this will fail with a conflict
git checkout --theirs <the file in question>   # this will overwrite the file with Ron's version of the file
# fix any other merge conflict
git commit                                     # finish merge
```